# How to have 2 advertisements in BLE(BlueTooth Low Energy)?

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on BLE advertisement. I'd like to know if it's possible to have 2 advertisements in BLE. I need to have both service data and manufacturer data. I'm using Python. The code is based on https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement.
I need to support EddyStone Beacon and some manufacturer data. But I don't know how to implement it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key item when wanting to do multiple advertisements, is that each advertisement must be created with its own unique D-Bus object path that it is published on.

In the BlueZ example they do this by having a `PATH_BASE` and appending the `index` value to it to make it unique:

```py
class Advertisement(dbus.service.Object):
    PATH_BASE = '/org/bluez/example/advertisement'

    def __init__(self, bus, index, advertising_type):
        self.path = self.PATH_BASE + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.ad_type = advertising_type
        self.service_uuids = None
        self.manufacturer_data = None
        self.solicit_uuids = None
        self.service_data = None
        self.local_name = None
        self.include_tx_power = False
        self.data = None
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)
```

They then use this unique path when calling `RegisterAdvertisement`:

```py
    ad_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(test_advertisement.get_path(), {},
                                     reply_handler=register_ad_cb,
                                     error_handler=register_ad_error_cb)
```

To make something that ran, I modified the BlueZ example. *These modifications focused on getting something to run with minimal changes rather than this is how I would do it in production.*

First, I changed the `TestAdvertisement` to do a different advertisement depending if it was called with index `0` or index `1`:

```py
class TestAdvertisement(Advertisement):

    def __init__(self, bus, index):
        Advertisement.__init__(self, bus, index, 'broadcast')
        self.add_service_uuid('FEAA')
        frame_type = [0x10] # Frame Type = 0x10
        power = [0x00]      # Power = 0x00
        if index == 0:
            prefix = [0x02]     # URL scheme = 0x02 (http://)
            url = [0x73, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x77, 0x65, 0x62, 0x73, 0x69, 0x74, 0x65, 0x07]
        elif index == 1:
            prefix = [0x01]  # URL scheme = https://www.
            url = [0x62, 0x6c, 0x75, 0x65, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x68, 0x00]
        eddystone_data = frame_type + power + prefix + url
        self.add_service_data('FEAA', eddystone_data)
```

I then modified where `TestAdvertisement` was called so it was called twice, once with `index=0` and once with `index=1`:

```py
    ad_manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter),
                                LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE)

    mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
    test_advertisement= []
    for ad_id in range(2):
        test_advertisement.append(TestAdvertisement(bus=bus, index=ad_id))

        print(f'{ad_id}: Registering advert path: {test_advertisement[ad_id].get_path()}')
        ad_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(test_advertisement[ad_id].get_path(), {},
                                         reply_handler=register_ad_cb,
                                         error_handler=register_ad_error_cb)

    if timeout > 0:
        threading.Thread(target=shutdown, args=(timeout,)).start()
    else:
        print('Advertising forever...')

    try:
        mainloop.run()  # blocks until mainloop.quit() is called
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Cleaning up advertisements')

    for this_ad in test_advertisement:
        ad_manager.UnregisterAdvertisement(this_ad)
        print('Advertisement unregistered')
        dbus.service.Object.remove_from_connection(this_ad)
```

I also modified the code to unregister both advertisements to clean up at the end.

The example should show two Eddystone URL beacons with different URL's.

Comment: Thanks ukBaz! For the knowledge of "you can have 2 adverts" and "iBeacon uses manufacturer_data while Eddystone beacons use service_data", I'm just wondering if  they are documented anywhere? Where did you get those knowledge? Thanks.

Comment: The different types are highlighted in the cheatsheet https://ukbaz.github.io/asset/beacon_packet_cheatsheet.jpg  type:ff=manufacturer_data  type:16=service_data.  Not sure there is a single reference to multiple advertisemetns. Knew it was a general capability of BLE and saw this reference in the BlueZ API https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/advertising-api.txt#n170

Comment: Thanks ukBaz! I posted a question about "Can not UnregisterAdvertisement() with the Beacon advertisement
": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63733137/can-not-unregisteradvertisement-with-the-beacon-advertisement. Please take a look to see if you know the answer.

Comment: I have another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821896/blebluetooth-add-notification-to-some-characteristics-caused-nrf-crash Please see if you know the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ukBaz! Your code works! I also tried to have 2 adverts with different contents: one has our own special data, the other one has the EddyStone-URL. The reason why we want to have advert 1 is because our mobile app wants to have a way to identify if the service is from our device. So we need a special manufacturer data such as "1234". Meanwhile, we also need to support EddyStone Beacon. So we need 2 adverts. I'm not sure if this is the best solution. Please comment.
I tried it. It seems working. Is there any side effect by having 2 adverts with different contents?
I changed the 'broadcast' to be 'peripheral' as our device is intended to be connected. Here is my code(I mainly changed the "if index == 0:" part):

```
class TestAdvertisement(Advertisement):

    def __init__(self, bus, index):
        Advertisement.__init__(self, bus, index, 'peripheral')
        if index == 0:
            # My code to have special manufacturer data and service UUID
            self.add_manufacturer_data(0x1234, b"1234567890")
            self.add_service_uuid("1234")
        elif index == 1:
            self.add_service_uuid('FEAA')
            frame_type = [0x10] # Frame Type = 0x10
            power = [0x00]      # Power = 0x00
            prefix = [0x01]  # URL scheme = https://www.
            url = [0x62, 0x6c, 0x75, 0x65, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x68, 0x00]
            eddystone_data = frame_type + power + prefix + url
            self.add_service_data('FEAA', eddystone_data)
```

As the comment doesn't support code well, I put it in one answer for the question.