# Can not UnregisterAdvertisement() with the Beacon advertisement

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez, beacon

I'm using BlueZ and Python to implement Bluetooth service. We have the requirement to be able to enable and disable the service and the Beacon. The idea is, we listen to some MQTT messages. If the message is to enable or disable the service/Beacon, we'll call the function to enable or disable it.
Here is the code of the advertisement:

```
class BluetoothAdvert(Advertisement):
def __init__(self, bus, index, name, MacAddress):
    Advertisement.__init__(self, bus, index, 'peripheral')

    if 0 == index:
        self.add_service_uuid('1234')
        self.add_manufacturer_data(0x1234, '123456789012')
    elif 1 == index:
        frame_type = [0x00]
        power = [0x00]
        id = [0x25, 0x33, 0x96, 0x2B, 0x17, 0xCD, 0xA2, 0x53, 
              0x77, 0x98, 0x22, 0x2A, 0x89, 0x12, 0x36, 0xF5]
        beacon_data = frame_type + power + id
        self.add_service_uuid('FEAA')
        self.add_service_data('FEAA', beacon_data)
```

Here is the code of the enable/disable the bluetooth service and the beacon advertisement:

```
def enableBluetoothService():
    service_manager.RegisterApplication(
        bluetooth_service.get_path(), 
        {},
        reply_handler=reg_callback, 
        error_handler=reg_error_callback)
    advert_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(
        bluetooth_advert.get_path(), 
        {},
        reply_handler=reg_callback, 
        error_handler=reg_error_callback)


def disableBluetoothService():
    service_manager.UnregisterApplication(
        bluetooth_service.get_path(),
        reply_handler=unreg_callback_func, 
        error_handler=unreg_error_callback)
    advert_manager.UnregisterAdvertisement(bluetooth_advert)


def enableBeacon():
    advert_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(
        beacon_advert.get_path(), 
        {},
        reply_handler=reg_advert_callback, 
        error_handler=reg_advert_error_callback)


def disableBeacon():
    advert_manager.UnregisterAdvertisement(beacon_advert)
```

Here is the main function:

```
def main():

    '''
    Other code ...
    '''
    
    service_manager.RegisterApplication(
        bluetooth_service.get_path(), 
        {},
        reply_handler=reg_callback, 
        error_handler=reg_error_callback)

    bluetooth_advert = BluetoothAdvert(bus, 0)
    beacon_advert = BluetoothAdvert(bus, 1)
    advert_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(
        bluetooth_advert.get_path(), 
        {},
        reply_handler=reg_advert_callback, 
        error_handler=reg_advert_error_callback)
    advert_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(
        beacon_advert.get_path(), 
        {},
        reply_handler=reg_advert_callback, 
        error_handler=reg_advert_error_callback)

    '''
    Other code ...
    '''
```

For the testing, it seems we can call enableBluetoothService() and disableBluetoothService() many times. The bluetooth service will be enabled or disabled. Is there any problems by calling enableBluetoothService() and disableBluetoothService() many times?

By calling UnregisterAdvertisement() with some data seems okay. But we can't call disableBeacon() then call enableBeacon(). Otherwise, we'll get "Failed to register advertisement: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists". Why can't we call UnregisterAdvertisement() with the Beacon advertisement?

Comment: In the BlueZ example advertisement they also do a `dbus.service.Object.remove_from_connection` https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement#n216 Have you tried that in your code?

Comment: Thanks ukBaz! It turned out that was my bad. I fixed it in our code. Now UnregisterAdvertisement() works. I am able to unregister the advertisement and register it again. By calling remove_from_connection(), the unregister doesn't work.